# How to Embedd youtube video in body field (converts URLs into embedded players)?

Tags: 8, files

Is there a simple way to insert youtube video in body field like other CMS where you copy a youtube link in the article body and it is automatically converted into a video player in front end.

I’ve search here and some topics talk about modules but there are not drupal 8 yet.

Is there a module that can do that or Drupal 8 maybe can do that natively ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve found and tested this module which do excaly what I want :

[Url to Video Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_to_video_filter)

> This module adds a new input filter that automatically converts URLs
>   for various video sharing websites into embedded players into the
>   text.

Here is a screenshot of the CKEditor filter :

[image]

I’ve tested this module on multiple sites and it works very well.

Currently this module supports the following services : YouTube / Vimeo

**EDIT**
Now, It also supports Youtube URL with parameter like `?rel=0` (`rel=0` is used to disable related videos shown at the end of a video)

Answer (score -1):

- Get the embed URL of the Youtube video which will be a iframe.
- Place that iframe markup in body field. Use Full HTML format to allow iframe tag.
- Since CKeditor is the default editor in Drupal 8, you can also use iframe tool.

Comment: Correct me i am wrong but you suggest to insert iframe code into body code ?

Comment: yes. you can place iframe markup in body field

Comment: I know how to do that and i don’t want to do that (it is not user friendly, very old school !) . I search an easy way to convert automatically youtube url into embedded video (like the native way on WordPress or Joomla (where you need an extension). If not possible, i search a CKEditor editor button maybe ?

Comment: If your requirement is not completely based on body field, you can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field

Comment: I know this extension and sometime i use it. Here, i just wan to integrate youtube videos in body between paragraph and images. So a video field is not appropriate.

Comment: Then I think you have to use iframe button in Ckeditor toolbar which is already there in Drupal.

Comment: Maybe but i still search. Here is one extension : https://www.drupal.org/project/url_to_video_filter that seems to do what i want. I test it now and I tell you.

Comment: See my answer. I've found an extension that converts URLs into embedded players.